# How do I find the minimum date using partition by in Kusto Query Language?

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

I have the following table `tb1`, where I'm trying to get the Minimum DDay without losing any columns or rows in KQL:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

I'm trying to avoid joining a summarized tb1 by SupplierID with tb1 again. I tried using `partition` as shown below but did not get the desired output.

```
tb1
| partition hint.strategy = shuffle by SupplierID (top 1 by DDay asc)
```

Comment: I think the above desired output is wrong. Is [this](https://i.imgur.com/RBXrFjb.png) the correct desired output as per your input data. If not can you explain your logic for the desired output?

Comment: My desired output is correct. The First_DDay column is the minimum DDay at a SupplierID level. For example, for Supplier ID 123, 12/1/23 is the minimum DDay in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand your request is that you want the minimum DDate by SupplierId, while maintaining the StoreId, DamageReported, etc. columns.

The constraint is that you don't want to summarize and join, but would you be happy with summarize and expand instead? In the following code, we

1. summarize and find the minimum date by Supplier and store the StoreId and DamageReported column into a list of elements to maintain the values in those rows.
2. We then expand those rows back from a list into individual rows using the `mv-expand` command. This command takes the scalar in the `First_DDay` and `SupplierId` columns and attaches them to every row in the list.
3. Use the `project` command to remove the `list_StoreId`, `list_DamageReported` columns that we had created earlier.

Sample code:

```
datatable(SupplierId:string , DDay: datetime , StoreId: string , DamageReported: string )
[
    "123", datetime(2024-01-23), "abe", "No",
    "123", datetime(2023-12-01), "az", "Yes",
    "45", datetime(2023-05-10), "wal", "No",
    "23", datetime(2024-01-01), "wal", "No",
    "45", datetime(2023-12-12), "az", "Yes"
]
| summarize First_DDay=min(DDay), make_list_with_nulls(StoreId), make_list_with_nulls(DamageReported) by SupplierId
| mv-expand StoreId = list_StoreId to typeof(string),
            DamageReported = list_DamageReported to typeof(string)
| project SupplierId, First_DDay, StoreId, DamageReported
```

Comment: It does the job! But I was looking for solutions that were along the lines of using Windows function in SQL ```First_DDay = MIN(DDay) OVER(Partition BY SupplierID)```